Living under a permanent dark
This is the 3. Part of a series of questions.
In which I asked how a permanent dark sky would effect flora and fauna.
Unlike the other two this question is not going to focus on nature. Rather how humans would be effected be affected by living under a permanent dark sky.
Though more directly speaking my question is what negative consequences would living with out natural light have on humans?
Assumptions
The sky is covered in dark clouds with the following properties:

Assume an European ecosystems
90% to 98% of sunlight is blocked
Higher frequency = higher block %
Lower frequency = lower block %
The conditions are PERMANENT

Irrelevant factors
Because I want to keep the question focused on the direct impact on humans we are going to assume the following things.

Assume food/water is not an issue
The temperature is livable
They still have oxygen

Important Considerations

Physical impact: Consider how such conditions could affect the human body. Also consider if vitamin D insufficiency would occur and how severe it would be.

Mental impact: Consider independent of the physical impact what consequences these conditions would have on the mind of a human. Like consider maybe how you may feel under such conditions.

No impact: If there is no significant impact on the human body just tell me in an answer. Consider humans in my world have access to artificial light with and 1980s technology in general.



Related questions:
Part 1: What fauna can survive a     permanently dark sky? 
Part 2: What fauna can survive a permanently dark sky?
Related: Highly resistant House Plant

I read somewhere about one person who cured "untreatable" seasonal affective disorder by the simple, not especially expensive, expedient of buying a few hundred lightbulbs and literally making the interior of their house exactly as bright as daylight for a few hours a day. Doing it with LEDs to avoid a fire hazard would be expensive in the 80s, but they had them.

Fluorescent lighting (i.e. not too hot), ultraviolet lighting (for vitamin D) were both available in the '80s. Vitamin D supplements were too. Does that hold true for your world?

@Escaped dental patient. Probably should be like that. Though would that really be enough to cure vitamin D deficiency?

To be fair, it's still a matter of debate in some circles as to if the supplement is as good as the real-thing. There are suspicions that there's more to sun-exposure than D production, but I'm not sure what the lacking substance/effect is. Melanin seems to have more of a metabolic effect than I previously suspected, but as far as I can tell the jury's still out on exactly what's up with that.

@Escapeddentalpatient. vit D deficency is detrimental enough for light skin to evolve in humans in only a few thousand years. the effect is thin brittle or even mishapen bones. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5986434/

Yeah, but if they've supplementation there still may be some effects apparently, but what and what magnitude I've no idea. @John

I don't think this question is answerable as posed. Food is both the main problem and the obvious solution to the secondary vitamin D problem. It can't be ignored.

@Escaped dental patient. Yes that is what i also thought that maybe Vitamin D supplements are not enough. Though i also heard that eating salmon is helpful.

@John this all takes place over about 150 years so there is no evolution going on At Least to my knowledge. So we are just focusing on the immediate consequences.

@g s i have not been asking for a solution for the vitamin D problem but rather if it would occur under these conditions. Just assume what happens if they don't take any countermeasure and just continue on as normal.

@JBH i didn't really give an answer in this question i just said that i am unsure if Vitamin D deficiency is a problem. I posed the possibility sure but i also said i am unsure if it would actually occur. It is just here to serve as an example of a possible solution might consider clarifying.

@JBH so that should hopefully fix the issue.

@Fallenspacerock yes a defiency will occur that was my point about evolution, lack of vitamin D is a serious problem. Vitamin D affected by light enough to force a rather rapid evolutionary change in human history.

@John i don't think 150 years are enough for humans to change drastically. I mean that are 6 to 8 generations at most evolution takes a long time. And if we consider that this dark sky slowly happened evolution seems Atleast to me even less like. But ofcourse if they had lived like that for millenia they would have adapted but they didn't.

@Fallenspacerock no people will not change, which is why they will suffer brittle malformed bones due ot a deficency.

@John yes this is more like what i thought would happen.

I think I would go insane without sunrises and sunsets to set my clock by, but people do live and work at the poles. It's entirely conjecture, but I think the human mind could adapt.
A modern industrialised society could afford to provide all its citizens with Vitamin D supplements. Currently, 20-30% of UK citizens have a Vitamin D deficiency (1). Rickets is not a public health crisis here. Your society will probably function fine with that rate at a hundred percent of citizens having a mild deficiency.
A society with eternal darkness is likely going to be more dangerous. Walking at night is more dangerous than during the day (especially if you're a woman). If your society has car culture, expect accidents to be more prevalent (2).

Thank you for your answer and yes i forgot that darkness is definitely something criminals would use. There by the way also other supernatural factors that make the world even more dangerous. Though do you think Vitamin D supplements could really make Vitamin D deficiency into a non deadly issue? Because i am unsure of how effective supplements actually are and if you don't need additional sources.

I'm no doctor but I don't see why not - I would imagine its how people survive polar night. If it's not an attractive solution though, I just remembered that in some parts of Siberia they expose children to ultraviolet light (kind of like a tanning bed) in the winter months to supplement the weak sunlight. (https://www.nationalgeographic.com/photo-of-the-day/photo/ultraviolet-bath-mcnally-pod) This has a side effect of looking really cool (should I edit my answer to include this?)

I'll probably have to research this somewhat more though i also heard that salmon is rich in vitamins D and makes a good source for it.

If temperature is still livable, we're either observing direct evidence of superhuman technology or other godlike powers, or a totally new understanding of the laws of physics. For the duration of time where human energy reserves hold out, the mental impact of literally coming face to face with a god or gods is likely to dominate the immediate impact. How humanity will react to undeniable evidence that a god or gods is real has been addressed in fiction regularly, but there is not a substantial backing of evidence for any particular result.

in terms of energy this is more meant as a simplifications there are other factors that keep the temperature livable. I just wanted to remove irrelevant factors from the question not to overload people with information. The only evidence of the supernatural is the sky though i don't think it's a proof of a god rather than it's the prove of the supernatural.
